# Conservar todos los archivos a mover de un directorio a otro

Tags: python

Este programa escrito en `pyton` trata de mover archivos de directorios a otro con el mismo name y con archivos dentro y los quiero conservar todos

```
import os
import shutil

source_folder = r"C:/Users/Yordany/Desktop/carpeta de trabajo/novela nueva/" # Aqui hay distintas carpetas con archivos
destination_folder = r"C:/Users/Yordany/Desktop/carpeta de trabajo/novela vieja/" # y esos archivos los quiero pasar para 
# las carpetas que se encuentran en esta direccion y tienen los mismos nombres que las carpetas donde estan los archivos
# pero que tambien hay carpetas en cada direcion con distintos nombres que no quiero tocar solo las carpetas que coincidan


while True:
    try:
        ruta = source_folder # Directorio a analizar
        carpetas_ruta_origen = os.listdir(ruta) # carpetas del origen de los archivos o sea de donde se van a coger los archivos
        for carpeta_ruta_origen in carpetas_ruta_origen: # creando la ruta donde se moveran esos archivos
            ruta_origen = source_folder + carpeta_ruta_origen + "\\" # ruta de donde se moveran
            ruta_destino = destination_folder + carpeta_ruta_origen + "\\" # ruta donde se moveran    
            #listar los ficheros de un directorio
            for archivos_mover in os.listdir(ruta_origen):           
                # construct full file path
                source = ruta_origen + archivos_mover
                destination = ruta_destino + archivos_mover
                # move file
                shutil.move(source, destination)
                try:
                    os.rmdir(ruta_origen)
                except:
                    continue
                print('Moved:', archivos_mover)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Todavia quedan archivos")
```

Con este código me funciona pero solo me toma la primera carpeta que compara.

Luego no me reconoce las demás, no se que me falta, si alguien me pudiera ayudar.

Comment: Utiliza el `shutil.move` a nivel directorio en lugar del nivel de archivo y con la opción copytree: shutil.move(dirOri,dirDes,copy_function=shutil.copytree)

Comment: muchas gracias fue perfecta la explicacion un gusto